# How to build the project in Apache Flink core?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm beginner in Apache Flink and can't find any information about extending Flink core. I want start with simple: to build in one test-class. should I save that class as jar-file somewhere in flink?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly.... You want to start with Flink development? Did you read the stuff on the project site about it: https://flink.apache.org/community.html and https://flink.apache.org/how-to-contribute.html and https://flink.apache.org/contribute-code.html and https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/setup/building.html abd https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Flink+Internals and

Comment: many of these links I haven't seen yet. seems to be, that I missed something. thanks=)

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to repost your comment as an answer

Comment: Well. Link-only answers are considered bad practice in SO...

Answer (score 0):

I recently started developing small programs with Apache Flink, so I had the same problem. I advise you to use maven because it will allow to link all the dependencies you need and easily build your own classes.

You need to first install maven and then you can create a Flink Maven project with the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.flink -DarchetypeArtifactId=flink-quickstart-java -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2
```

after that can add your classes to the src/main/java/[GroupId]../ and compile them with:

```
mvn package
```

Then, to run you newly created program you can execute the following command:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Package.YourClass" -Dexec.args="YOUR PROGRAM ARGUMENTS"
```

There are also tutorials all over the internet of how to run maven with an IDE if you want to.